# GraphQL & MongoDB cursors

Tags: mongodb, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I'm confused about what should be the relation between GraphQL's cursors and MongoDB's cursors.

I'm currently working on a mutation that creates an object (mongo document) and add it to an existing connection (mongo collection). When adding the object, the mutation returns the added edge. Which should look like:

```
{
  node,
  cursor
}
```

While node is the actual added document, I'm confused on what should be returned as the cursor.

This is my Mutation:

```
const CreatePollMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'CreatePoll',

  inputFields: {
    title: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },
    multi: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
    },
    options: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLList(GraphQLString)),
    },
    author: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
    },
  },

  outputFields: {
    pollEdge: {
      type: pollEdgeType,
      resolve: (poll => (
        {
          // cursorForObjectInConnection was used when I've tested using mock JSON data, 
          // this doesn't work now since db.getPolls() is async
          cursor: cursorForObjectInConnection(db.getPolls(), poll), 
          node: poll,
        }
      )),
    },
  },

  mutateAndGetPayload: ({ title, multi, options, author }) => {
    const { id: authorId } = fromGlobalId(author);
    return db.createPoll(title, options, authorId, multi); //promise
  },

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late for you, but maybe it will help someone else stumbling across this problem.

Just return a promise from your resolve method. Then you can create your cursor using your actual `polls` array. Like so:

```
resolve: (poll =>
    return db.getPolls().then(polls => {
        return { cursor: cursorForObjectInConnection(polls, poll), node: poll }
    })
)
```

**But careful**, your `poll` and the objects in `polls` have different origins now and are not strictly equal. As `cursorForObjectInConnection` uses javascript's `indexOf` your cursor would probably end up being `null`. To prevent this you should find the object index yourself and use `offsetToCursor` to construct your cursor as discussed [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/issues/29).